# Hide Back Button Title on iOS 13

Tags: ios

Our application has a deployment target of iOS 10. We're hiding all back button titles (for the entire app) with the following code

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.001),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.clear
]

let barButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self])
barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .highlighted)
```

This worked up until iOS 13, where the back button titles are no longer hidden.

I saw the WWDC 2019 video about the new apperance APIs, but as far as I can tell it only told me how to use the new APIs for a single navigation bar (and not for the entire app).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Add in viewDidLoad() method of the parent(previous in the stack) controller.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

In the next screen, only the arrow image will be presented.

or you can put this code before pushViewController method, for example

```
func presentNextScreen(_ controller: UIViewController){
   // Suppress title in the back button on the next screen.
   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: This is a pre iOS 13 way of doing it. Doesn't work on iOS 13+

Comment: @dvdblk, it works for iOS 13. these function from one of my project:
func presentEditor(_ controller: UIViewController){
        // Hide navigation Item Title in the next controller
        // Suppress title in the back button on the next screen.
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry! If you edit the answer I can cancel my downvote.

Comment: I've provided 2 variants that I was using in iOS13. I faced this issue by myself and spent some time to find a solution. The variant from my comment I've described too.

Comment: This is the only sane way of doing it. Remember that you might need to give a non-empty title (i.e., @" ") though for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the easiest way to hide the title in the back button is to configure the appearance of UINavigationBar

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let standartAppearence = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            standartAppearence.configureWithDefaultBackground()

            let backButtonAppearence = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
            let titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
            backButtonAppearence.normal.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes
            backButtonAppearence.highlighted.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes
            standartAppearence.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearence

            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standartAppearence
            UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = standartAppearence
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = standartAppearence
        }
```

In addition, here you can add any other configuration of the navigation bar

Comment: This solution is not optimal. Users can tap on the clear colored label and the back action is still triggered.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:
Create a base class: BaseViewController.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

func hideBackButton() {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
}

func hideCloseButton() {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
}

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addNavigationButtons()
}

func addNavigationButtons() {
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "close"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeTheFlow))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = closeButton
}

@objc func goBack() {
    //Go Back
}

@objc func closeTheFlow() {
    //Close
}
```

Make every ViewController a subclass of BaseViewController.
You could do anything with the right and left buttons in the entire app.

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible for our project, but I have temporarily solved it by setting `standardAppearance` for our root view controllers navigation bar, which seemed to extend to every other view, so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I hide title gloabal. a trick

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, vertical: 0), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```